# Replace specific text while ignoring spaces

Tags: c#, text, replace, space

I need to replace text in C# while ignoring any spaces.

For example:

```
"This is a text with some tags <UL> <P> <LI>", 
"This is a text with some tags <UL>   <P>    <LI>", 
"This is a text with some tags <UL><P>    <LI>" or 
"This is a text with some tags <UL><P><LI>"
```

must all be replaced with

```
"This is a text with some tags <UL><LI>"
```

Note that I just cannot remove spaces from the whole string and then replace the required string, since that would give a wrong result -

```
"Thisisatextwithsometags<UL><LI>"
```

I am sure that the 3 tags

```
"<UL>", "<P>" and "<LI>"
```

will be present in that order, but am not sure of the spaces between them.

Answer (score 1):

Use `String.Replace`:

```
string text = "This is a text with some tags <UL>   <P>    <LI>";
int indexOfUl = text.IndexOf("<UL>");
if (indexOfUl >= 0)
{
    text = text.Remove(indexOfUl) + text.Substring(indexOfUl).Replace(" ", "").Replace("<P>","");
}
```

**Old Answer** (worked before your last edit):

```
string[] texts = new[]{"<UL> <P> <LI>", "<UL>   <P>    <LI>", "<UL><P>    <LI>" , "<UL><P><LI>"};
for(int i = 0; i < texts.Length; i++)
{
    string oldText = texts[i];
    texts[i] = oldText.Replace(" ", "").Replace("<P>", "");
}
```

or - since the question is not very clear(*"must all be replaced with `<UL><LI>`"*):

```
// ...
texts[i] = "<UL><LI>"; // ;-)
```

Comment: I am not sure beforehand how many spaces would be there between the text. so it cannot be put in an array.

Comment: @user2751130: I don't understand your comment. You have provided several sample strings that you want to modify. I have added these strings to a collection to show you a way how to remove the white-spaces and `<P>`-tags. So the spaces are not related to the array at all. I could also remove the array and use three different string variables.

Comment: Hey @TimSchmelter, OP added details. This answer no longer works for his purpose. Just wanted to let you know.

Answer (score 1):

Have fun with Regex!

```
Regex.Replace("<UL>   <P>    <LI>", "<UL>.*<LI>", "<UL><LI>", RegexOptions.None);
```

Replace the first parameter with your string that you need altered, and if there is <UL>(any characters no matter what they are including spaces)<LI>, it will replace all of that with just <UL><LI>.

Answer (score 0):

Try using Regex:

```
Regex.Replace(inputString, "> *<", "><");
```

Comment: -1 This doesn't work at all. On his first example, this is the result: This is a text with some tags <UL><P><LI>. He doesn't want the <P> to remain. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

assume that < UL> tag is in every string.

```
  string[] stringSeparators = new string[] { "<UL>" };
  string yourString = "This is a text with some tags <UL><P><LI>";
  string[] text = yourString.Split(stringSeparators, StringSplitOptions.None);
  string outPut = text [0]+" "+ ("<UL>" + text[1]).Replace(" ", "").Replace("<P>", "");
```

Answer (score 0):

just look here **[String MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.aspx)**

also for replasing use **[String.Replace(string string)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk49wtc1.aspx)**